# SQL Unit Test log/output order of execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have a few unit tests (around 50) that I have created for testing the stored procedures in my database project. When I run them using "Run all Tests" some tests fail. So, I run them individually and they all pass. So I can see that the order of execution is somehow inserting dodgy data in some tables that is causing an issue.

So I would like to know if there is a method to log or output (in the test window) what is the order of the unit tests that was run. Since they run quickly and the order changes every time I run, I cannot be sure of what run when. The Test Output window only holds when the Test was started and when it finished.

> ------ Discover test started ------
>
> ========== Discover test finished: 52 found (0:00:00.4010401) ==========
>
> ------ Run test started ------
>
> ========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:13.4663465) ==========

I would like to see something like this,

> ------ Discover test started ------
>
> ========== Discover test finished: 52 found (0:00:00.4010401) ==========
>
> ------ Run test started ------
>
> ------ TestA started ------
>
> ------ TestB started ------
>
> ========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:13.4663465) ==========

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use tSQLt, an open source unit test framework which uses transactions to roll back changes after each test. This means you always return to a known good state for the next test.

You can integrate tSQLt with VS unit testing using Ed [Elliott's tSQLt adaptor](https://the.agilesql.club/blogs/Ed-Elliott/tSQLt-Visual-Studio-Test-Adapter).

Answer (score -1):

First, unit tests should never go past a certain scope (the unit, generally a class). In other words, you shouldn't touch the DB or read files - that's already integration testing.

Second, unit tests should be able to run independently from each other, and not rely on any external state - just test that unit of code in isolation.

That being said, when writing tests that alter or require a certain state it's important to ensure that the appropriate set up is done for each and every test, so that one doesn't require another one to be run before. This could be as simple as configuring your `[SetUp]` method to insert some seed data, before removing it on `TearDown`. If different tests require different seed data, you'll have to do that in the actual test.

Finally, you should be able to grasp the test execution order by running them in the command line (using `nunit-console.exe`)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. However, we have pre and post scripts that run specifically for every stand alone unit. For some reason, when executing the single unit - it passes, but when testing all the units by "Run all Unit Test" is when some of them fail. We needed to know which test runs prior to the failing one and concentrate on seeing what is the state of the db, when the test completes.

Comment: you might want to look into Visual Studio's [Ordered Tests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286704(v=vs.120).aspx)